# Rails 4 eager loading a model within model

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have the following:

```
class ObjectA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one   :object_b
end

class ObjectB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to   :object_a
  has_one   :object_c
end

class ObjectC < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to   :object_b
end
```

So doing ObjectA.eager_load(:object_b) will eager load the ObjectB obviously.
But i'm trying to eager load the entire hierarchy without having to issue a new query every time I call: object_a.object_b.object_c

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like

```
ObjectA.includes(object_b: :object_c).where(...)
```

This will eager load `ObjectA`'s related `ObjectB` and the nested `ObjectC` for each `ObjectA` matching the `where(...)` conditions.

If you're looking to avoid duplicating the above query format whenever you want to do the eager load, you could make a class method on `ObjectA`.

```
class ObjectA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one   :object_b

  def self.with_related(conditions)
    includes(object_b: :object_c).where(conditions)
  end
end
```

Reference: **[Eager Loading of Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations)**